# how to read the appconfig ldap through the nunit

Tags: c#, ldap

How to read the app.config through the nunit in C# when debugging the nunit it does not read the app.config settings for eg:
the ldap ://192.12.178.0 setting value is added in app.conifg but does not and returns null
in which i want to pass the ldap value to and authenticate the aduser

Answer (score 1):

App.Config files apply only to the executing process not to any libraries called by the process. NUnit has its own executable which runs the unit tests therefore it uses the NUnit executables app.config file. If you add it to the Nunit app.config (which i don't recommend) this will work.

What i recommend you do instead is pass the configuration property into the class constructor from higher up in the call stack (where you can get it from the app.config if you like), and then in your unit test manually pass the configuration setting to the class under test.